# Draw interactive Tree Diagram

Tags: diagram

I want to build a document for my organization. It should have a very big tree diagram (or organization chart) that does not fit in a word or excel page. I used Excel smartart tool to draw it. It was easy. But I want to have one or several pages that describe each node. If I want to describe it in web, a good solution would be a web page with the tree and each node of the tree is a link that to a page of description with user click (or an ancher in the same page). It is a good one but it's not the best. I see very beautiful charts with d3 for example, or very nice other diagrams with jquery or other things.
What is the solution? I don't want to program for such a document. Any WYSIWYG free tool that could make such a documentation could help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I myself could find one. I don't know whether is the best or not but it satisfied me. I could draw the diagram with [coggle mind mapping chrome extension](https://coggle.it). The good thing is that its node can be link to a page. So, you can build a documentation. It needs some efforts, but it's good! :-)